# VPN сервер на Windows 8.1

Tags: tp-link, vpn, windows-8

Создал VPN-сервер на Windows 8.1 следующим образом -> http://goo.gl/qV08Np

Windows 8.1 с поднятым VPN-сервером находится за маршрутизатором TP-LINK TL-WR841N. Внутри сети IP-адреса раздаются посредством DHCP. На данную ОС зарезервирован постоянный IP-адрес 192.168.0.100. На маршрутизаторе прокинут порт 1723 для PPTP. Включен "Пропуск трафика PPTP".

Пробуем подключиться к VPN-серверу с клиентской машины. Зависает на "Проверка имени пользователя и пароля". В результате, ошибка 806.

Вопрос — что неверно настроено?!

PS: На маршрутизатор залита последняя прошивка (3.14.19 Build 130620 Rel.63894n).PPS: С клиентской машины телнетом успешно цепляюсь на порт 1723 VPN-сервера.PPPS: На VPN-сервере антивирусное ПО отключалось. Не помогло. :(

Comment: Тут, похоже, есть ограничения количества комментариев, поэтому отвечу здесь:  Justicet, я сейчас администрю три сервера под вендами, один из которых не в России. Вот там нет никаких рутеров, конкретный внешний IP. Если вы не поняли, то я про это. А дома у меня - Kubuntu, и не жалуюсь! Я, кстати, официально состою в команде переводчиков Ubuntu, если это вам интересно!

Comment: @Anton  Reshin , я понял про что Вы писали. Мне кажется, что хватит нам вести пустую полемику, причем еще и в нескольких темах.  По теме:  1) отключите временно файерволл;  2) пробросьте на рутере порт 47 (GRE-протокол).  Если не выходит, попробуйте:  >Поскольку новая реализация IPsec NAT-T для нормальной работы служб требует открыть следующие порты и протоколы (support.microsoft.com/kb/818043).1) Internet Key Exchange (IKE): порт User Datagram Protocol (UDP) 5002) IPsec NAT-T: UDP-порт 45003) Encapsulating Security Payload (ESP): протокол Интернета (IP), порт 50

Comment: Поправочка - не порт 47, а протокол GRE (номер 47)

Answer (score 1):

Варианты причины проблемы:
1. Не пускает провайдер
2. Не пускает роутер
3. Не пускает фаерволл.
4. Всё же криво настроили.

Соответственно пути анализа:
0. Ставим WireShark, очень сильно поможет, на всех этапах он запущен на сервере и смотрит - что прилетает
1. Втыкается напрямую сервер в интернет, пытаемся на него законнектиться. Проверяем - удалось ли? Отрубаем фаерволл (вредно, если сервер жалко), или только для доступа с определенного ип адреса даём абсолютно полный доступ и снова пытаемся коннектиться.

Если уже на этом этапе коннекта нет, а фаерволл точно не виноват, общаться с техподдержкой провайдера. Как добились стабильного соединения, крутим правила фаерволла, чтобы не позволять совсем всё, а только нужное. Итого устранили 1,3,4.

На этом этапе - если входящих пакетов нет даже при отключенном фаерволле - проблема или на коннектящемся клиенте или на провайдерах с обоих концов. Если страшно пускать в инет сервер, можно и по локалке сначала оттестить, но внимание к правилам фаерволла, что работает в локалке, во внешке может и не завестись.

Заодно помимо WireShark поглядываем в журнал событий Windows, иногда там пишут умные вещи.

2. Втыкаем роутер в инет, сервер в роутер. Наблюдая в Wireshark, пробуем коннектиться и настраиваем правильный пропуск пакетов роутером.

--- 99. Покупаем хотя бы MikroTik hAP lite (цена вопроса 1.5к рублей и да, я люблю микротики и нет, мне не доплачивают), ломаем голову об мануалы и админку, поднимаем полноценный удобный и замечательный VPN с колхозницами и шахматами и радуемся жизни.

Answer (score 0):

А что в логах ВПН-сервера? Логах рутера?
Есть ли в логе коннект ВПН-сессии-клиента на ВПН-сервер?
Ну и для начала, я бы все-таки, разрешил пропуск любого трафика, пока идет настройка и проверка...

Comment: И tcpdump было бы очень полезно посмотреть, а также маршруты

Answer (score -1):

Если доходит до вендов, то ищи в их логах! А чтобы совсем просто - отруби дурацкий  вендовый файрволл!

Comment: Файрволл в вендах - это то ещё "будьте-здрасьте"! В упор, пока не отрубил, пытался не пускать меня по RDP в офисной локалке, которую сам же и делал, зато великолепно всё работало через Тимвьюер! Это вот как понимать изволите???

Comment: Второй интересный момент - надо запретить некоей проге общение наружу (кто-то уже догадался, почему). Прописываю правила на отруб в файволле вендов - ан, нет! Пофиг! Не работает! Слава Богу, там ещё и KIS был! Вот там прописал, что типа - нефиг, и всё получилось как надо!

Comment: Да и зачем вообще делать VPN сервер на 8.1, если для этого есть Windows Server 2012 - кстати, очень даже неплохой???

Comment: Я скажу свое имхо: Я вообще не понимаю зачем делать VPN-сервер на Виндах. Ибо, мое мнение такое: VPN делается для доступа в локальную сеть предприятия (фирмы, дома) извне (то бишь снаружи). Поэтому VPN-сервер должен крутиться на маршрутизаторе. Соответственно роутер либо железо, либо комповый - но тогда уж там точно Винде делать нечего... А в конфигурации топикстартера - все же использовал бы опенсорсные решения.   А VPN внутри локалки предприятия - это уж, извините, извращение.

Comment: Если в офисной локалке есть вендовый сервер, то VPN делается именно на нём, другого-то нету! А VPN там применяется обычно для удалённой работы. Все проблемы - в реализации.

Comment: В **нормальной** офисной локалке обычно существует более-менее приличный рутер, который умеет VPN.  Если же приключилась ситуация, что рутер не умеет VPN, или по результатам у него немерено потребляются ресурсы и приходится отказаться от VPN на нем ради нормальной работы сети, то следует поставить в локалке еще один сервер на ОпенСорсе, который и будет заниматься VPN. Древнюю машинку для этого - в любом офисе найти реально.  Я против размещения всего на одном сервере. Ибо не стоит все яйца класть в одну корзину.